# Fetch images and upload to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, async-await, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to download the given results (URLs of Images) to google cloud storage. 
The code runs in a firebase function and is is triggered by pub/sub.
Everything with the unsplash API works fine, the for-loop is also looping but it's not saving the images to cloud storage or throwing any error. I am out of ideas what could be the fault.

```
 // Search Photos on Unsplash
      unsplash.search.photos('searchTerm', 1, 5, { orientation: "landscape" })
      .then(toJson)
      .then(async res => {

        const images = res.results;

            for (const image of images) {
              await fetch(image.urls.raw)
                .then(result => {

                  // The Part that is not working
                  result.body.pipe(storage.bucket('bucket-id.appspot.com/').file(image.id+".jpg").createWriteStream());

                  return true;
                });
              } 
          });
```

Comment: Have you tried using [upload()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) instead of createWriteStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible causes:

- The `WritableStream` from `createWriteStream()` isn't being closed properly.
- Your cloud function is being terminated too soon.

Normally, [`ReadableStream.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) will close the stream for you by default - as long as there are no errors. When an error is encountered during piping, the target won't ever be closed.

To aid debugginng, attach an error listener to the `ReadableStream` and see if it's complaining about anything:

```js
result.body.on('error', (err) => console.log('Encountered an error while piping file: ', err));
```

In addition to a potential uncaught error, using `body.pipe()` is an asynchronous operation but your function handler is immediately returning `true` indicating that your Cloud Function is okay to terminate.

To get around this, wrap the `body.pipe()` in a Promise. You can also link up the error handler from above to reject the promise.

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const readStream = result.body;
  const writeStream = storage.bucket('bucket-id.appspot.com/').file(image.id+".jpg").createWriteStream();

  readStream.on('error', reject);
  writeStream.on('error', reject); // may as well connect it
  writeStream.on('finish', () => resolve(true)); // fired by pipe() when it's done

  readStream.pipe(writeStream);
});
```