# Designing Cloud Functions to stream downloads to Google Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a workflow where I want to download many large (500 MB - 1.5 GB) files each day from an external server and upload the file to GCS. Each file has its own endpoint. Due to restrictions on the external server that I download each file from, each download can take a few minutes. I was thinking of using a Cloud Function where I send the URL of each file, and the function downloads the file locally, then uploads it to GCS. However, to do so, I would need one of the large Cloud Function instances (2 GB). These can get quite expensive -- is there a way to use a lower memory instance and stream the result to GCS directly?

Comment: Seems possible: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming

Comment: 1) Cloud Functions is very inexpensive. Instance performance is related to memory size. Smaller sizes may result in longer execution times. https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing 2) Double-check how much networking ingress/egress will cost (possibly $0.12/GB). https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing 3) Factor in Cloud Logging ($0.50/GB), etc. 4) I have functions that only cost $10.00 per month but networking costs $150.00 per month.

Comment: What the alternative to Cloud Function? Have a VM? Agree with John, Cloud Functions is very affordable, especially for this type of workload that runs only few minute per day. You can also consider Cloud Run is you need more memory or longer timeout.

Comment: Here some relevant questions where file streams are piped to Cloud Storage: [Piping file from a form to GCS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58889204/3068190), [Piping response from `fetch()` to GCS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356499/3068190).

Answer (score 1):

If you are transferring data from other Cloud Service Providers you can use Storage Transfer Service which will only cost you the Network charges as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/pricing)

If you are transferring the data from your on-premises server then you can use Transfer service for on-premises data and schedule the transfer service as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/schedule-on-prem-jobs) where you can set up the interval to be in Weeks, Days or Hours . This will cost you $0.0125 per GB transferred to the destination successfully in addition to the networking cost. As you are more concerned about time being needed to download if you use Cloud Function which in turn increases the cost you may consider this as it will not cost you per time rather per GB of data.

You can use Streaming Transfers as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) which allow you to transfer data to Cloud Storage without saving data to a file. Streaming uploads to Cloud Storage are helpful when we usually don’t know the final size of the data that is being uploaded at the starting of upload.